# JavaScript and HTML for reach buttons

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="number">
                <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
</div>
```

how can I reach button values when i click with javascript?

Comment: (Not a great duplicate closure as that duplicate is primarily jQuery-focused.)

Comment: `document.querySelector(".number").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const btn = e.target.closest("button");
  if (!btn) return;
  console.log(btn.value);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the `.value` property on the button.  Here's a demo I made where you can click each button and it will log the `value` to the console.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.number button')
  .forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(btn.value);
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="number">
  <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
  <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You may find [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) useful here. One listener on the container rather than one listener on each button. @fhumanity

Comment: @fhumanity please mark my answer as accepted if this answers your question